# How to add Date in crystal Report c#

Tags: c#, date, crystal-reports

in my app I am showing a date in my crystal report and I have a column which is the number of months but it is a text in my database.
 So, I create a formula field where I do the addition of the date and the month in order to get the new value of the date but I got an error telling me that the field is not numerical.
Here is my code to add the date

```
CDate(DateAdd ("M",ToNumber({TableName.interval}) ,{TableName.date} ))
```

TableName.interval is of type text and TableName.date is of type Date in my database.

Comment: your formula worked for me... 
just a note, try to remove the CDate I guess it will also work!

Comment: yep you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the CDate function I guess it will also work. Your final fomrula must look like:

```
DateAdd ("m",ToNumber({TableName.interval}),{TableName.date} )
```

Comment: I did all these at AUB and USJ :p (hope you understood)

Comment: Well, welcome to SO... If you need any help dont hesitate to ask!